# Finding the angle of ellipse

Tags: angle, ellipse

I have an ellipse without any information about the angle and semi-axis(short and long), I just have 100 points that are the bounds of ellipse. How can I finde these parameters?

Soroor

Comment: Well, the first thing you should do is to go to a site devoted to computer programming questions to ask this math question twice.

Answer (score 0):

You have more points than you need. Assuming all those points are on the ellipse (and not a bounding box):  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163920/how-to-find-an-ellipse-given-five-points

Comment: but I just have the boundary of ellips no more information and I need to find other parameters.

Comment: Read the question again. The question he referenced uses 5 of those points frome the boundary to get all of the parameters that define the ellipse.